# How to use GROUP BY and result with highest id value

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I used the following query to get the result

```
SELECT  `subjects`.*,`staffs`.`name`
    FROM  `subjects`
    LEFT JOIN  `staffs`  ON `staffs`.`uid` = `subjects`.`teacher`
    LEFT JOIN  `subject_student_selective`
       ON  `subject_student_selective`.`course` = `subjects`.`classid`
      AND  `subject_student_selective`.`subject` = `subjects`.`subject`
      AND  `subject_student_selective`.`student` = '12947'
    WHERE  `subjects`.`classid` = '26'
      AND  `subjects`.`active` = '1'
      AND  (`subjects`.`type`='normal'
              OR  `subject_student_selective`.`id`>0
           )
    GROUP BY  `subjects`.`subject`
    ORDER BY  `subjects`.`sort_order`
```

This gave the result but, I need to get the result with highest ID'ed Group By subject.

Comment: add max(uid) in the select

Comment: Unless subject, classid, active is a candidate key of subjects, your query will produce indeterministic results.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For the one row with the highest ID:

```
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

For the "latest" information associated with each `subject`, the problem is considerably more complex.  Search for "groupwise max".  Here's one link:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Comment: Or use [MySQL8 window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html)

Comment: @Xenos - Yes.  (and MariaDB 10.2)  How about presenting an Answer with a clean example of using a Windowing function for groupwise max.